# Does $\text{cov}(\lVert X-X' \rVert, \lVert X-X'' \rVert) \geq 0$ hold for i.i.d. random vectors?

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, random-variables, covariance

Let $X$, $X'$, and $X''$ be i.i.d. random vectors taking values in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Is it true that

$$\text{cov}(\lVert X-X' \rVert, \lVert X-X'' \rVert) \geq 0?$$

My numerical simulations suggest that it is, but I have so far only been able to show the following:

- $\text{cov}(\lVert X \rVert, \lVert X \rVert) = \text{var} (\lVert X \rVert) \geq 0$
- $\text{cov}(\lVert -X' \rVert, \lVert -X'' \rVert) = \text{cov}(\lVert X' \rVert, \lVert X'' \rVert) = 0$
- $\text{cov}(X-X',X-X'') = \text{var}(X) \geq 0$ for $X, X', X''$ with dimension $1$

Comment: Try Y'=X-X' and Y"=X-X".  Should be direct.

Comment: @herbsteinberg We get $\text{cov}(\lVert Y' \rVert, \lVert Y'' \rVert) = \mathbb{E}\lVert Y' \rVert \lVert Y'' \rVert - (\mathbb{E}\lVert Y' \rVert)^2$. Any hints from here?

Comment: I am a little confused about your norm.

Comment: It's the usual $\ell^2$-norm. How can I help clarify?

Comment: What is the range space of the random variables?

Comment: @herbsteinberg $\mathbb{R}^N$ (I'll edit that into the question)